# Segmenting a wav file with an XML using Java

Tags: java, wav, javasound

I have a bunch of wav files and corresponding XML files which contain times.

What I need to do is split the wav files based on the times inside the XML files.
Parsing the XML files shouldn't be a problem, but I need to know the best way to get a portion of the wav file and save it into a new wav file.

Is there a certain library I can use, or is Java's Sound API the best approach to use?

I'd do it manually using Audacity, but there are a hours of them, and that would take too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future referece, I'm going to use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net) to do the trimming, and I'm going to use it through Java's ProcessBuilder. It's useful, because I just found out I need to be able to change the sample rate of some of the files. Also, if I didn't have to convert the sample rates of any of the files, I would've just gone with a [WavFile class](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) created by Dr. Andrew Greensted. Even if it isn't that well documented, studying it really helped me understand the wav file specification and review endianness and bitwise functions. It lacked the ability to convert sample rates, which is a complex process, so I had to drop it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) could be used to do this. [Here is a guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html), chapter 5 and 6 should be interesting for you.

But you should also note that the last stable release lays eight years back. Wikipedia provides a [list of alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives), see if you can find something that suites your needs.